# g++ optimization for overloading operator

Tags: c++, optimization

I wrote header for arr class in arr.h with overloaded `=` operator for 1D-array and checked for the time needed for

`A=B`, where `A`, `B` arrays.

Time was comparable to the time in the simple loop for `double` array (without class `arr`) for optimization level less than 3.

```
#!/bin/bash 

FLAG=$1
echo $FLAG

g++ -o main $FLAG -std=c++11 main.cpp   -DARR && main
g++ -o main $FLAG -std=c++11 main.cpp         && main

# end of the script
```

> CMP -O0 ; CMP -O1 ; CMP -O2 ; CMP -O3 ; CMP -Ofast

gives

-O0

- with    `ARR`:    1.5790530000000000e+00 4.3474900000000000e-01 2.0138020000000001e+00
- without `ARR`:    4.0454800000000002e-01 4.4675500000000001e-01 8.5130300000000003e-01

-O1

- with    `ARR`:    8.7386200000000003e-01 2.8413300000000002e-01 1.1579950000000001e+00
- without `ARR`:    3.3455699999999999e-01 3.5522599999999999e-01 6.8978300000000004e-01

-O2

- with    `ARR`:    7.2507600000000005e-01 2.3888400000000001e-01 9.6396000000000004e-01
- without `ARR`:    3.3509400000000000e-01 3.5229899999999997e-01 6.8739300000000003e-01

-O3

- with    `ARR`:    6.1693299999999995e-01 2.3233400000000001e-01 8.4926699999999999e-01
- without `ARR`:    2.3794000000000001e-01 1.9999999999999999e-06 2.3794199999999999e-01

-Ofast

- with    `ARR`:    6.2396699999999994e-01 2.3364900000000000e-01 8.5761599999999993e-01
- without `ARR`:    2.3897499999999999e-01 1.9999999999999999e-06 2.3897699999999999e-01

But for `-O3` and `-Ofast` simple loop demonstrates dramatic decrease of time (second column with numbers). How can I get the same result for `arr` class?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>

#ifdef ARR
#include "arr.h"
#endif

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n=1e8;
    register int i; 

    clock_t time1=clock(),time2,time3=0;

#ifdef ARR
    arr<double> A(n),B(n);

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        B(i)=i;
#else
    double * A = new double [n];
    double * B = new double [n];

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        B[i]=i;
#endif

    time2=clock();

#ifdef ARR
    A=B;
#else
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        A[i]=B[i];
#endif

    time3=clock();

#ifdef ARR
    cout<<fixed<<setw(16)<< scientific <<setprecision(16) <<" with    ARR:    "<<(time2-time1)/ (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC<< " "<< (time3-time2)/ (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<  " "<< (time3-time1)/ (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl;
#else
    cout<<fixed<<setw(16)<< scientific <<setprecision(16)<<" without ARR:    "<<(time2-time1)/ (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC<< " "<< (time3-time2)/ (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<  " "<< (time3-time1)/ (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl<<endl;
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

arr.h

```
#ifndef ARR_H
#define ARR_H

using namespace std;

template <class T> class arr
{
public:
    T* data;
    int size, dim=0;
    int dim1=0, dim2=0, dim3=0, dim4=0;
    int shape[4];

    arr() { }   

    arr(const int & isize) {   //  constructor
        dim=1;
        size=isize;
        dim1=size;
        data = new T[size];
        shape[0]=size;

        register int i;
        for (i=0; i<size; i++)
            data[i]=0.;
    }

    ~arr() {  delete [] data; }

    T &operator()(const int & index) { 
        return data[index];
    }

    arr &operator=(const arr & A) {
        register int i;
        for (i=0; i<size; i++)
            data[i]=A.data[i];
        return *this;
    }

    arr &operator=(const T & A) {
        register int i;
        for (i=0; i<size; i++)
            data[i]=A;
        return *this;
    }
};

#endif /*ARR_H */
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't do anything with `A` after copying the array, the optimizer is completely removing the loop.  You need to use some value in the `A` array (for example, output one element of the array in your `cout` statement).